# サロゲートペアを持つ""を171581として表示させるには？

Tags: javascript, 文字コード

以前、お世話になり、ありがとうございました。
知識が不足してるにもかかわらず、再びの質問でお世話になります。
以前、入力された文字列を変換するのに、以下のコードを教えていただきました。
 => 55399,56893になります。これを
 => 171581と変換するには、どこを変えたらいいのでしょうか？それとも、JavaScriptでは不可能なのでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
function decodeString(){
  var src = document.getElementById('src').value;
  var dest = '';
  for(i=0; i < src.length; i++) {
    dest += src.charCodeAt(i) + ',';
  }
  document.getElementById('dest').value = dest;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-16のサロゲートは1文字目の先頭6ビットが`110110`であるかどうかで判別できます。

符号は先頭を除いた下位10ビット×2に格納されているのですが、サロゲートが使用される場合は16ビットで表現できない場合ですので実際の値は`2^16`が減算される仕様になっています。
ですので結局

```
((1文字目 & 0x3ff) << 10) + (2文字目 & 0x3ff) + 0x10000
```

で元の符号の値を求めることが出来、繰り返し処理は以下のようになります。

```
for(i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    var c = src.charCodeAt(i);
    if (i + 1 < src.length && (c & 0xfc00) == 0xd800) {
        var c2 = src.charCodeAt(++i);
        dest += ((c & 0x3ff) << 10) + (c2 & 0x3ff) + 0x10000 + ",";
    } else {
        dest += c + ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: 素早い回答ありがとうございます。ご説明いただいた内容は、知識不足のため、完全に理解できませんが、思い通りの結果が出せました。たぶん、自分の力では、５年かかりそうでした（笑い

Answer (score 5):

単一の例では要件がはっきりしませんが、おそらく文字のUnicode符号位置を値として取得したいということと理解しました。この用途でいえばネイティブの実装を用いるならば[String.prototype.codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)が利用できます。

```
console.assert("".codePointAt(0) === 171581); // U+29E3D
console.assert("".codePointAt(1) === 56893); // lower; 56893
```

`String.prototype.codePointAt`のインデックスは従来通りUTF-16符号化に基づく文字数、すなわち、

```
console.assert("".length === 2);
```

と数えてしまう仕様ですから、単純なインクリメントで「各文字に」ついて処理をするのは不適切です。codePointAtを用いれは次のように書き直せます。

```
const src = "a0Ａてすbと";
const dest = [];
let i = 0;
while (i < src.length) {
    const codePoint = src.codePointAt(i);
    dest.push(codePoint);
    i += codePoint > 0xFFFF ? 2 : 1;
}
console.log(dest); // Array [ 97, 48, 65313, 12390, 171581, 12377, 98, 12392 ]
```

これはサロゲートペアのときは「jsにおいて2文字分」、それ以外は通常通り「jsにおいて1文字分として」インクリメントして、それぞれの文字について符号位置を取得するものです。

ちなみに、Stringオブジェクトの既定イテレータである[String.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator)は**サロゲートペアをサポートします**。

> The @@iterator method returns a new Iterator object that iterates over the code points of a String value, returning each code point as a String value.

こちらを用いれば先ほどのコードは次のように書けます。

```
const src = "a0Ａてすbと";
const dest = [];
for (const char of src) {
    dest.push(char.codePointAt(0));
}
console.log(dest); // Array [ 97, 48, 65313, 12390, 171581, 12377, 98, 12392 ]
```

ただし、`String.prototype.codePointAt`,`String.prototype[@@iterator]()`,`for...of statement`はいずれも比較的新しい機能です。アプリケーションのターゲット環境がこれらをサポートしているかについて、互換性を十分確認してください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ただ、知識不足のため、コードを置き換える作業ができませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

一応ECMAScript 2015(ES6)の場合は、以下のようにも書けます。

IEを除くモダンブラウザであれば、動作するかと思いますが、ターゲットとされているブラウザで動くかどうか事前にご確認されたほうが良いかと思います。

```js
const str = "a0Ａてすbと";
const result = [...str].map(c => c.codePointAt(0)).join();
console.log(result);
```

**参考URL:**
JavaScript Stringでサロゲートペアを扱う - teppeis blog
http://teppeis.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/surrogate-pair-in-javascript

Comment: ありがとうございます、ご指摘通り、自分のブラウザでは、残念ながら、以下の結果になってしまいましたが、回答ありがとうございました。Error: {
  "message": "構文エラーです。",